# Tornado secure websocket timeout

Tags: python, sockets, ubuntu, tornado, iptables

My server got 2 Ip's (**ip1 & ip2**) i recently added ip2. When i try to open my tornado websocketserver on ip1 (where `apache2` is running) everything is fine, i specify a port e.g. 22000 and can connect to my `socket` via `wss://domain.tld:22000/sub`

However as soon as i configured tornado to listen on **ip2** (where apache is not running), because i have to use the port 443, which is blocked by apache on ip1, I can't connect to it via `wss://sockets.domain.tld:443/sub`. The `DNS` A record points to ip2.

> The connection times out. No matter which port or protocol (wss / ws) i use.

My python code:

```
from tornado import web
from tornado import ioloop
from tornado import websocket
from tornado import httpserver
import ssl
import json
import random
import re
import os

application = web.Application([(r"/sub", Client)])
http_server = httpserver.HTTPServer(application,  ssl_options = {
    "certfile": os.path.join(LIB_DIR, "certificate.crt"),
    "keyfile": os.path.join(LIB_DIR, "certificate.key"),
})
http_server.bind(443, address = "ip2")
print("Listening to ip2:443")
ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

My Server is running on `Ubuntu 12.2`, I opened the ports and checked with an external tool if they are open.

[image]

How can i fix this? Has it something to do with my server?

**UPDATE**
I'm quite sure it has to do with `http_server.bind(...)`, the code does work with `.listen(port)`, but ip1 and bind does also not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httpserver.html), after the call to `bind`, you should call `start` on the server. So

```
http_server.bind(443, address = "ip2")
print("Listening to ip2:443")
http_server.start()
ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

should work.